# two Y capacitors used as protective impedance

Tags: capacitor, impedance

Can two "Y" capacitors be in series and used as protective impedance bridging primary and secondary where the secondary circuit is accessible?

Comment: Two (or more) capacitors in series still appear as one capacitor. Why would this be an issue? What do you mean by 'protective impedance"?

Answer (score 0):

UL60950 / IEC 60950 / EN 60950

If the plastic case of your AC/DC product has no apertures or has small apertures that though don't allow people to touch hazard voltages, than all the mentioned safety norms allow you not to use a transformer.

Under those conditions you may use a polyester capacitor in series to a fuse.

A fuse is always mandatory.

In my projects I use UL recognized or UL listed polyester capacitors and fuses for transformerless AC powered products.

Take a look at "transformerless power supplies".

Y capacitors are allowed to bridge primary and secondary circuits and are used only for EMI reasons.

If you use two Y capacitors in series, the overall value of the capacitance may be too low to draw power from the mains.